# Powershell object property names case sensitive?

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script in our test system that accessed some SCCM objects and their properties. All the property names of these objects were entered in lower case and it all worked.
I then ported the script to our production environment and the script failed. What I discovered was that all the object property names had become case sensitive! So instead of $var.name, I had to use $var.Name. I could not find any option in powershell that turns property names into strict case sensitive. Anyone know of such an option? We are running Powershell V3 btw.

Comment: Some code examples that exhibit the problem would be helpful

Comment: Actually I had another question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945220/powershell-accepting-and-assigning-null-or-empty-arguments-in-pipeline) which includes the code I am talking about. In the first code snippet you can see that the select statement uses lower case "name", "version" etc. When I ported this code to production I have to change this to "Name" and "Version" for example.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour, it seems that the sccm provider (CMSite) is effectively case sensitive, this is really unusual !

Answer (score 2):

For the most part Powershell is Case Aware but not Case Sensitive.

Many exceptions however can be found in external cmdlets or functions that have been made available to Powershell such as `[ADSI]` and `LDAP` or even `[Regex]`

I've also noticed in my scripting that `ForEach` likes the properties to be in lower case but it's the only specific commands I've encountered with this preference.

It seems to be quite a weird topic as well but doing a quick search i found a few articles that were a good read

[Technet Discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b95eb187-16fe-41d0-bd8e-2f22b1e5f140/query-userprincipalname-usign-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)

and linked with

[Similar Technet Discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/78e10a25-deca-4378-bc45-5c5d2ee5734c/powershell-case-sensitivity)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that there are indeed many case sensitive ares like LDAP etc. It's just that I have never seen this duplicitous behaviour where a script works in one environment and fails in another because of case sensitive property names.